# how to check To email is inside or outside orgnization?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

How i can check Email address is inside or outside organization in outlook add-ins is there any build in function for that?
I tried to use domain check but what if the organization have multi emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this API to know the recipient type. The recipient type would be of ExternalUser if the email id is not present on the exchange server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailboxenums.recipienttype?view=outlook-js-preview